# Dataframe changing question with time series data with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

I have this dataframe:

[image: dataframe]

The event-time is certain time, date-time column is every 10 min with a specific price. Continues for 4 hours after event time and 2 hours before the event for each security. I have thousands of securities. I want to create a plot that i x-axis starts from -12 to 24 which is event time to -2 hour to 4 hours after. y-axis price change. Is any way to synchronize date-time in python for security.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to simply plot the data pandas should handle your datetimes for you assuming they are in datetime formats instead of strings.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

event_time = pd.to_datetime('2024-04-28T07:52:00')
date_time = pd.date_range(event_time, periods=24, freq=pd.to_timedelta(10, 'minute'))
df = pd.DataFrame({'date_time': date_time, 'change': np.random.normal(size=len(date_time))})

ax = df.plot(x='date_time', y='change')
plt.show()
```

[image: image1]

However if you're wanting to remove the specific times from the x axis and just count up from zero you could use the index as the x-axis:

```
df['_index'] = df.index
ax = df.plot(x='_index', y='change')
plt.show()
```

[image: image2]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, forgot to tell that I have thousands of different events that have the same structure, I want to synchronize all them that start from 0 to 24. Every Security have prices for every 10 minutes for 4 hours after the event. I want to synchronize all this time-line of different securities. I don't if I'm being clear.